# Does singular values have anything to do with eigen-values of a square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

We know from linear-algebra, how to calculate the singular values $\sigma_{n(A)}$ of a square-matrix, $A$ by square-rooting the eigen-values of $A^*A$ i-e $\sigma_{n(A)}=\sqrt{\lambda_{n(A^*A)}}$.

But, I need to know that does singular-values, $\sigma_{n(A)}$, of a square-matrix have anything to do with eigen-values, $\lambda_{n(A)}$, in principle ?

thanks

Comment: Note thet a non-square matrix does NOT have eigenvalues, but it does have singular values, so the question does only make sense for square matrices.

Comment: Relate d to  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33089/majorization-relation-between-the-absolute-values-squared-of-the-entries-of-a-ma

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I'm asking only about square-matrices. Question edited. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The following paper contains (much) information related to your Q: www.scirp.org/journal/PaperDownload.aspx?paperID=41122‎          See also the book Marshall, Olkin, Arnold:  "Inequalities: Theory of majorization and its applications. second edition" Springer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Marshall, Olkin, Arnold: "Inequalites: Theory of majorization and its applications (second edition)", (Springer), page 317, gives the following theorem (Weyl, 1949).

For any $n \times n$ complex matrix $A$, where the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are ordered such that 
$$
    |\lambda_1| \ge |\lambda_2| \ge \dots \ge |\lambda_n|
$$
and the singular values $\sigma_i$ are in decreasing order, we have:
$$
\prod_1^k |\lambda_i| \le \prod_1^k \sigma_i, \qquad k=1,2,\dots,n-1
$$
and with equality above for $k=n$. In the case with no zero eigenvalues, this corresponds to log-majorization.

The reference above contains a proof.

Comment: +1 vote. Thanks for coming up with more elaborative relation than mine.

Answer (score 4):

$$|\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i|=\prod_{i=1}^n\sigma_i    \quad\quad for \quad  A^{n\times n}.$$

Where $\lambda$ and $\sigma$ are eigenvalues and singular values of $A$, respectively.

Comment: Do you have a reference (or proof) for that? Seems highly unlikely!    For instance, the nilpotent matrix $\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}$ have both eigenvalues zero and one singular value zero, the other 1, so is an counterexample.

Comment: so what ? $|0 \times 0| = 0 \times 1$.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Now, after proving  by yourself, it proves that equality $|\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i|=\prod_{i=1}^n\sigma_i$ is correct for any arbitrary square matrix. So ... Still -1 vote?

Comment: My vo|te is locked-in (after one hour, it seems). To change, you must first edit your answer, such as putting in some proof or reference.